# How fast CEL events are written to the database?

Tags: asterisk

My program should notify its subscribers about new calls, ended calls, transfers and so on.

I can listen to CEL events in the AMI, but simpler solution would be to query database every X seconds and handle records from there, since I'll have to do it anyway to handle calls that took place when my program wasn't running.
*(Yeah, I know, usually pushed events are better then polling, but not in this case, IMO)*

But I'm not sure how fast CEL events are dumped into the database. Is there any delay or queue?

I've tested on my local Asterisk and events appeared in the database right away, but on some highly loaded instances this may not be so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no queue.
When the backend database CEL driver is loaded, it initializes the connection to the database. When an event happens, it basically blocks the execution of that call, untill the database operation finishes (succeeds, fails, times out).

If ODBC is used, that is a bit different as I remember. It handles database transactions and cursor, but still no queue. I'm not sure about connection pooling.

Comment: This behaviour is also the drawback of Asterisk. It's not suitable for high traffic systems.

Comment: There isn't any connection pooling, just like there isn't any queue. If you're an expert, you can find RabbitMQ / Redis / Memcached CEL module source codes. These will save to memory, and won't block the call. Drawback is that you need to write code, to put it into the database later.